# Use Lexical Variable Declared in For Loop in Continue Block

Tags: perl

I am having trouble getting one of my modules to compile with what looks a variable scoping issue, but I don't understand why.

*Sample Code*:

```
PATH: foreach my $path (@paths) {
    open(my $file, '<', $path) or next PATH;

    my %properties;
    LINE: while (<$file>) {
        $_ =~ /$property_regex/ or next LINE;
        $properties{$1} = $2;
    }

    foreach (@property_keys) {
        unless ($properties{$_}) {
            # do stuff
            next PATH;
    }

    if ( $irrelevant_condition ) {
        # do stuff
        next PATH;
    }

    foreach my $new_var (@new_list) {
        # do stuff (does not iterate PATH loop)
    }
} continue {
    if (defined $file) { close($file) or die; }
}
```

---

Translated to the stripped down code above, the error I'm getting is:

> Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at line 25

Namely, it seems to be complaining about the use of `$file` in the `continue` block at the bottom. As you can see, `$file` is declared as a lexical variable on line 2, within the outer foreach loop (labelled PATH).

However, based on the [perldoc for continue](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html), I would expect `$file` to still be in scope:

> [...] it is always executed just before the conditional is about to be evaluated again, just like the third part of a for loop in C. Thus it can be used to increment a loop variable, even when the loop has been continued [...]

In order to be able to increment a loop variable, wouldn't the continue block have be treated as part of the same lexical scope as the loop to which it is attached?

What am I missing?

---

*Note: This module is a Moo class, so while I do not have an explicit `use strict` statement anywhere, [when you use Moo we enable strict and warnings](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo#INCOMPATIBILITIES-WITH-MOOSE).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$path` variable is still in scope inside the `continue BLOCK`, but the stuff inside `for`'s BLOCK is out of scope because you've reached the end of that BLOCK (you've hit the end brace / exited the braces). The `$path` variable, however, is not inside the braces, so can be visible inside the `continue BLOCK` (even though it's not visible beyond that).

If the syntax were like this:

```
for (...)
{
 $x = stuff();
 continue { more_stuff($x) }
}
```

then I would expect `$x` to be visible. IIRC, perl 6 has stuff like this, but in perl 5, the `continue BLOCK` is outside the loop's block, and thus doesn't see lexical variables inside that block.

Comment: So basically "loop variable" in this context only refers to the iterator, and not anything else within the body of the loop?

If `continue` doesn't have access to the lexical variables inside the for loop, is there some other obvious method of ensuring the old file handle is closed after each iteration?

Comment: @BryKKan it'll automatically be closed when it goes out of scope and the reference count on it drops to 0.

Comment: The proposed syntax doesn't actually help. Imagine `for (...) { next; my $x = 13; continue { ... $x ... } }`. I mean, we could still do it, but it introduces another case of undefined behaviour. Worse, it's one that's that's super easy to invoke by accident. Maybe that leading `next` wasn't there originally, but it gets added later... Whenever the `continue` block comes up, I think how much nice it would be to have it within the loop block, but that just wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The loop variable is garanteed to have been declared before the `continue` block is evaluated, so that variable can be provided to the `continue` block.

But any part of the the loop block can be skipped (e.g. using `next`), so Perl doesn't know at compile-time which of the loop block's variables will be declared when the `continue` block is entered, so it can't make any of them available to the `continue` block.

---

If you're not content with the file handle getting closed automatically (e.g. because you want to detect write errors), you could use a scope guard instead of a `continue` block.

```
use Sub::ScopeFinalizer qw( scope_finalizer );

for my $qfn (@qfns) {
   my $fh;
   my $guard = scope_finalizer {
      if ($fh) {
         close($fh)
            or die("Error writing to \"$qfn\": $!\n");
      }
   };

   open($fh, '>', $qfn)
      or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

   ...
}
```

Comment: +1 `Perl doesn't know at compile-time which of the loop block's variables will be declared when the continue block is entered` - I hadn't considered that, probably because my variable was declared on the first line, and therefore (seemingly?) guaranteed to exist. Of course, as I now see, from the perspective of the compiler, that's not true of the rest of the block, and may not even be true for some edge cases on the first line (i.e. conditional execution).

Comment: The compiler could study the code and determine it's safe to use a variable, but that would feel even weirder than the current situation to programmers. For one, programmers would have to make the same analysis the compiler does to figure out exactly when a variable gets freed. This could matter if it contains an object with destructor.

Comment: Agreed. I just hadn't considered it from the perspective of someone trying to write a compiler until you pointed that out.

Comment: My last comment is suppose to point out it would be weird from the perspective of the programmer too. Being simpler for the compiler not to handle it isn't reason enough not to handle it.